# File path does not change while using netrw in vim

Tags: vim, netrw

While editing a file in vim and opening another file in a second split with netrw, the current working directory does not change and the path is same as the first file opened. Is there any way to fix this?

The following mapping in the .vimrc does change the path of the working file but it also sets the same path for the rest of the files opened in vim.

```
nnoremap <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<CR>:pwd<CR>
```

I also viewed questions based on this but couldn't find an appropriate solution.

A solution for this would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for [`:lcd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:lcd) (local `cd`)?

Comment: Yes, this does the job . But why doesn't netrw change the path by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a language barrier issue, but you can't really expect Vim to change the path of a file when editing it.

What you want to change is probably the "working directory". If so, you can simply do it with `:help 'autochdir'`:

```
:set autochdir
```